# How Do i import Variable Amount from one Class/Constructor to the other?

Tags: java

Im a Begginer to Java and woule like so insight here. int gives an nullexception and i dont think using Integer here is a good practice because later on i will have to use the int Pages but as it will be Integer i will have to keep using (Integer.valueOf(17) == 17); just to make an Integer an int as Integer cannot be compare to an int.

```
class Book {

  private int Pages; // Ive tried Changing it to Integer!
  private String Author;
  private String Title;

  public Book() {

  }
  public Book (String title, String author, int pages){
      Author = author;
      Title = title;
      Pages = pages;
        }
  public void setauthor(String author){
       author = Author;
  }
  public void settitle(String title){
      title = Title;
  }
  public void setpages(int pages){
      pages = Pages;
  }
  public String getauthor(){
      return Author;
  }
  public String gettitle(){
      return Title;
  }
  public int getpages(){
      return Pages;
  }
 public String printBook(){
      if ( Pages == 0 || Pages == null){
          return "Title: " + Title + ",  "+ "Author: " + Author + ",  " + "Pages:"  + "1";
      }
      else{
    return "Title: " + Title + ",  "+ "Author: " + Author + ",  " + "Pages:"  + Pages;
}
}
}
```

//  Mainclass

```
public class TestBook {

  public static void main(String[] args) {


    // = = = =
    // Instantiating an empty Book object; for example: Book1, for testing
    Book  Book1 = new Book("Renewable Energy","John Smith",209);
    Book  Book2 = new Book("Harry Potter PS ","JK Rowling",null);
    Book  Book3 = new Book("Harry Potter PA ","JK Rowling",-1);

    System.out.println("Test for object Book1");
    System.out.println("=====================");
    System.out.println(Book1.printBook());
    System.out.println(Book2.printBook());
    System.out.println(Book3.printBook());

}
}
```

Comment: Please follow Java naming conventions. Instance variable names start with a lowercase letter: `author` instead of `Author`. If you want to differentiate it from a method argument called `author`, use `this.author` to refer to the instance variable.

Comment: And, in answer to your question, you're doing your assignments the wrong way round in your setters - it should be `Pages = pages;`, or `this.pages = pages;` if you follow the above advice.

Comment: Thank you ! Kinda new to this !